# How to map a String to an application object in Mapstruct

Tags: java, spring, mapstruct

Let's say I have this UserRole class.

It contains the roles of each user.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user_roles")
public class UserRole implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column
    private long userRoleId;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "users_fk"), nullable=false)
    private User user;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "roles_fk"), nullable=false)
    private Role role;

    ...

}
```

Now I want to have a DTO class with just userName and role that will map to the original class.

```
public class UserRoleRequestDTO {
    
    private String userName;
    
    private String role;

    ...
}
```

How do I create a mapper for that?

```
@Mapper
public interface UserRoleMapper {
    
    @Mapping(//** What goes here? **//) 
    UserRole UserRoleRequestDTOtoUserRole(UserRoleRequestDTO userRoleRequestDTO);
    
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `@Named` ? https://www.baeldung.com/mapstruct-custom-mapper

Comment: To be clear, your issue is how to map between `String` and the corresponding `enum` of the field?

Answer (score -1):

Before using a library, look at the documentation, you will always find the solution to common problems.

[MapStruct 1.5.3.Final Reference Guide](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/)

You can also look at the documentation of the Mapping annotation:

[@Mapping](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/api/org/mapstruct/Mapping.html)

If you have all the information from requestDTO to populate the User and the Role you need ([Controlling nested bean mappings](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct-examples/blob/main/mapstruct-nested-bean-mappings/src/main/java/org/mapstruct/example/mapper/FishTankMapper.java)):

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface UserRoleMapper {

    @Mapping( target = "user.userName", source = "userName" )
    @Mapping( target = "role.role", source = "role" )
    ...
    ...
    UserRole toUserRole(UserRoleRequestDTO dto);

}
```

There is also a project on GitHub with many examples:

[mapstruct-examples](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct-examples)
[mapstruct-examples -> mapstruct-nested-bean-mappings](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct-examples/tree/main/mapstruct-nested-bean-mappings)